# Drawable file wont change color in Dark Mode

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-dark-theme

Im currently working on a LoginActivity, I wanted to make an rounded Linear to put the Edittext's inside, I used an XML file to round the corners of them, but the only problem is, that they wont change their color in dark mode.

I already used the colors from the @colors file, but it wont affect at all, I tried to use cardview instead of a Linearview with an drawable file as background, but it breaks the layout.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/design_default_color_on_primary"/>
    <stroke android:width="0dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

LoginActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/login_bg1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/loginbg"
        android:elevation="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:layout_marginVertical="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_primary"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_box"
            android:elevation="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_email"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColorHint="@color/design_default_color_primary"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="44dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_box"
            android:elevation="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_password"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColorHint="@color/design_default_color_primary"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Login"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Maybe someone knows to fix this issue.

Comment: do you have `values/colors.xml` and `values-night/colors.xml` files with different values for : `@color/design_default_color_on_primary`? Really you should try to use `?attr` style syntax for referencing colors (like Android does - `colorOnSurface`, `colorPrimary` etc) and creating custom attr values rather than referencing colors directly, it makes it far simplier when you want to change or update themes.

Comment: I only have colors.xml and 2 Themes one for day and one for night, I used the colors from the themes like "colorPrimary" wich is in both themes, just in slightly different version.

Comment: You are referencing colors directly, if you haven't defined 2 states for the same colour then it won't change? As suggested either create 2 color.xml files, or create your own attr value that points to different colors in each theme which should be the preferred way to do this.

Comment: I used attributes, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support dark mode you need a separate colors.xml file for the night version. To create colors file for night mode. Follow these steps.
Right-click on values folder
New > Value Resource File
In the Available Qualifiers search for Night mode and click on the (>>) button.
From the drop-down select Night
Name the file as colors

And define all the night mode colors here

Names of the colors will be the same as the Non-Night colors file

Another way to create colors.xml for night mode is
On the top left corner click on Android and Switch to project,
Go to folder app > src > main > res and create a new folder and name it values-night and inside that folder create an XML file named colors.xml

Comment: I just used Attributes, and it worked.